# Javascript event to change its child to checked

Tags: javascript

I want an event in which when i click the list tag so the radio button gets checked.

```
<li class="morning-time">
    <div class="morning-icon"></div>
    <div class="timeTxt">Morning <span>7am - 12am</span></div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="option-input checkbox" id="rbt_Time1" name="rbt_Time" value="1" data-text="Morning 7am - 12am">
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Don’t need JavaScript, put a `<label>` around the whole thing. (Remove the existing one first, fixing `.checkBox` styles if necessary.)

Comment: can you share your attempt (code)?

Comment: I havent attempted it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to include jquery for using the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.morning-time').on('click', function(){
    $('.option-input', $(this)).prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

Here, on li(class='morning-time'), the radio(class='option-input') is searched inside(the li tag) and set checked.

Answer (score 0):

You need [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) to do so AND to explain the code, radio styled input have [*a checked attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio). Just *set it to true* and the input get check.
Here the code :

```
function CheckMe()
{
    var radioInput = document.getElementById("rbt_Time1");
    radioInput.setAttribute("checked", "true");
}
```